# How to use ng-messages within repeated md-input-container

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

With Angular 1.5.5 and Angular-Material 1.0.9 I have created a HTML form like this with a repeated `input` element. I want to use `ngMessages` for the error messages. The problem I have is that when I enter for example `-1`, the correct error message is shown in a tooltip, but not below the input element. The issue seems to be that the `ng-messages` attribute does not support interpolation like the `input`'s `name` attribute. I could put a variable into the `$scope` which contains the correct name, but I am not happy with that option because then the `input`'s `name` is defined in the  HTML template and the JavaScript controller. Is there a way to do this more cleanly?

```
<form name="form">
  <md-input-container ng-repeat="product in purchase.products">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="9999" ng-model="product.quantity"
      name="product[{{$index}}].quantity"> 
    <div ng-messages="form.product[$index].quantity.$error" md-auto-hide="false">
      <div ng-message="min">Please enter 0 or more</div>
      <div ng-message="max">Please enter 9999 or less</div>
    </div>
  </md-input-container>
</form>
```

To be extra clear: In the rendered DOM, there is `<input name="product[0].quantity"` while `ng-messages` does not change and `$index` is not evaluated. I guess I would need an expression that evaluates to `"product[0].quantity"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `name` *property* to:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="9999" required ng-model="product.quantity" name="product_{{$index}}">
```

And your `ngMessages` to:

```
<div ng-messages="form['product_' + $index].$error">
```

Now it should work.

Comment: It's true I forgot the `form` prefix, but adding it doesn't solve the problem because `$index` is not evaluated in this place.